# Making header width align with both columns

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, two-column, tufte

I'm trying to design a header for `tufte-book` class. I've managed to do this:

[image]

But I need to have a header aligned with both columns, not just one:

[image]

please help me to do this.

---

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{biditufte-book}
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\normalsize\bfseries #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\normalsize\bfseries #1}{}} % Section text font settings
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{16.5pt}% fancyhdr tells you the length
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \small
  \makebox[-5pt][r]{ \pagenumbox{1cm}}%
  \pagehead{\quad\quad\quad\quad\nouppercase{\leftmark}\hfill}%
}
\fancyhead[LO]{%
  \small
    \makebox[-275pt][r]{ \pagenumbox{1cm}}%
  \pagehead{\hfill\nouppercase{\rightmark}\quad\quad\quad\quad}%
}

%\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
%  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
%  \fancyhf{}%
%  \fancyfoot[L]{ \pagenumbox{\textwidth}}%
%}


\newcommand{\pagenumbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt
  \colorbox{blue!20}{\pagestrut
    \makebox[#1][c]{\thepage}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\pagehead}[1]{%
  \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt
  \colorbox{blue}{\pagestrut
    \makebox[\textwidth][s]{#1}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\pagestrut}{%
  \vrule width 0pt 
    height 1.5\ht\strutbox 
    depth 1.5\dp\strutbox
}
% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}

\usepackage[localise=on]{xepersian}
\settextfont{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}
\chapter{مشاهده‌‌پذیری}
\ptext
\section{مقدمه}
\ptext[1-10]
\section{مقدمه}
\ptext[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I guess probably - maybe - `\hfill` fills the left header space. Probably you need to figure out the full width you want of the header. Are there fonts in TeX Live we can reproduce this with?

Comment: yes, I think ``Zar`` or ``B Zar`` works.

Comment: @cfr Or you can simply download ``XB Zar`` [HERE](http://dl.irmug.com/dl.php?id=2)

Comment: ``Times New Roman`` works too!

Comment: Anyway, I don't get the point of changing the layout of tufte-book. Probably it would be easier for you to modify another class, `memoir` for example

Comment: TNR won't work on Linux!

Comment: How about ``Arial`` or ``Tahoma``??

Comment: Thank You but it does't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need full page header, you should compute the full width of your blue rule. As you can see on the image below (where text areas are shown using `\usepackage{showframe}`), the width of your rule equals the width of your text area + the width of your margin area + the length in-between. Thus :

```
\newlength{\bluerulelength}
\setlength{\bluerulelength}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\bluerulelength}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\bluerulelength}{\marginparwidth}
```

(you also need to compute another length so that your light-blue box is well positionned, see below.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{biditufte-book}
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\normalsize\bfseries #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\normalsize\bfseries #1}{}} % Section text font settings
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{16.5pt}% fancyhdr tells you the length

\newlength{\bluerulelength}
\setlength{\bluerulelength}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\bluerulelength}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\bluerulelength}{\marginparwidth}

\newlength{\pagenumberboxskip}
\setlength{\pagenumberboxskip}{-\bluerulelength}
\addtolength{\pagenumberboxskip}{1cm}
\addtolength{\pagenumberboxskip}{10pt}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
    \small
    \makebox[-5pt][r]{ \pagenumbox{1cm}}%
    \pagehead{\quad\quad\quad\quad\nouppercase{\leftmark}\hfill}%
}
\fancyhead[LO]{%
    \small
    \makebox[\pagenumberboxskip][r]{ \pagenumbox{1cm}}%
    \pagehead{\hfill\nouppercase{\rightmark}\quad\quad\quad\quad}%
}

%\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
%  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
%  \fancyhf{}%
%  \fancyfoot[L]{ \pagenumbox{\textwidth}}%
%}


\newcommand{\pagenumbox}[1]{%
    \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt
    \colorbox{blue!20}{\pagestrut
        \makebox[#1][c]{\thepage}%
    }%
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\pagehead}[1]{%
    \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt
    \colorbox{blue}{\pagestrut
        \makebox[\bluerulelength][s]{#1}%
    }%
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\pagestrut}{%
    \vrule width 0pt 
    height 1.5\ht\strutbox 
    depth 1.5\dp\strutbox
}
% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
    \clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \fi}

\usepackage[localise=on]{xepersian}
\settextfont{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{مشاهده‌‌پذیری}
    \ptext
    \section{مقدمه}
    \ptext[1-10]
    \section{مقدمه}
    \ptext[1]
\end{document}
```

---

### Previous answer

Your issue comes from the fact that, for odd pages, your defining the *left* part of your fancy header. You should instead use :

```
\fancyhead[RO]{%
    \small
    \makebox[0pt][r]{ \pagenumbox{1cm}}%
    \pagehead{\hfill\nouppercase{\rightmark}\quad\quad\quad\quad}%
}
```

(Note that it's now `\fancyhead[RO]` and `\makebox[0pt]` instead of `\fancyhead[LO]` `\makebox[-275pt]`, respectively).

I have added the display of text areas boundaries using `\usepackage{showframe}`. You can remove it in your final document.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{biditufte-book}
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\normalsize\bfseries #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\normalsize\bfseries #1}{}} % Section text font settings
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{16.5pt}% fancyhdr tells you the length
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
    \small
    \makebox[-5pt][r]{ \pagenumbox{1cm}}%
    \pagehead{\quad\quad\quad\quad\nouppercase{\leftmark}\hfill}%
}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
    \small
    \makebox[0pt][r]{ \pagenumbox{1cm}}%
    \pagehead{\hfill\nouppercase{\rightmark}\quad\quad\quad\quad}%
}

%\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
%  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
%  \fancyhf{}%
%  \fancyfoot[L]{ \pagenumbox{\textwidth}}%
%}


\newcommand{\pagenumbox}[1]{%
    \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt
    \colorbox{blue!20}{\pagestrut
        \makebox[#1][c]{\thepage}%
    }%
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\pagehead}[1]{%
    \begingroup\fboxsep=0pt
    \colorbox{blue}{\pagestrut
        \makebox[\textwidth][s]{#1}%
    }%
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\pagestrut}{%
    \vrule width 0pt 
    height 1.5\ht\strutbox 
    depth 1.5\dp\strutbox
}
% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
    \clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \fi}

\usepackage[localise=on]{xepersian}
\settextfont{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{مشاهده‌‌پذیری}
    \ptext
    \section{مقدمه}
    \ptext[1-10]
    \section{مقدمه}
    \ptext[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but  want to have header above both columns not just one like the picture in my post.

Comment: but the number moved! is there any other way of positioning that number box??